# After converting image to different format, app keeps returning empty file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a MVC app that will let the client upload an image, convert the image to a different format (.tif in this case) and return it to the client.

The problem I'm getting is that the image is always 0kB. I can't seem to figure out the problem.

The view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input accept=".bmp, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg" name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

The controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult UploadImages(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var tiffEncoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
            .SingleOrDefault(dec => dec.FormatID == ImageFormat.Tiff.Guid);
        Stream imgStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (EncoderParameters encParams = new EncoderParameters(1))
        using (Image img = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream, true, true))
        {
            encParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100);
            img.Save(imgStream, tiffEncoder, encParams);
        }
        var result = File(imgStream, "image/tiff", "image.tif");
        return result;
    }
```

Upon debugging I clearly see that the FileStream property contains data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imgStream` needs to be rewound after writing. Set `imgStream.Position = 0;` before passing it into `File`

Comment: Sheesh, that was a fast response.

Comment: @Jakov sorry, I'll try to be slower next time :)

Comment: You should. I can't even mark this as the correct answer yet and I have stuff to do :)